# Cannot set UIScrollView contentSize based on UIIMage

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I am struggling for 2 hours now to get a UIScrollView.contentSize with the size of a UIImage, but the UIImage doesn't return a proper size, I have no idea why.
The result is that my scrollView  content is square(the same as the scrollView's frame) and I can't scroll to the side of the image.
This is really frustrating! You can see in the debugger that my image1.size is invalid.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have been struggling with this for a while now, and finally I was able to find the answer. The problem was indeed in the content size, and I was finally able to calculate it correctly as below:
let tempScrollView = UIScrollView(frame: self.imageLocationsArray[imageID])
        let tempImageView = UIImageView(image: image)

```
    //determine proportions of image against frame
    let imageWidthFactor = image.size.width / tempScrollView.frame.width
    let imageHeightFactor = image.size.height / tempScrollView.frame.height

    //image is too wide
    if imageWidthFactor > imageHeightFactor {
        tempImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tempScrollView.frame.width * imageWidthFactor / imageHeightFactor, height: tempScrollView.frame.height)
    }
    //image is too tall
    else {
        tempImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tempScrollView.frame.width, height: tempScrollView.frame.height * imageHeightFactor / imageWidthFactor)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are accessing an image from array which doesn't exist see your console log it's clearly saying index out of range. that's why your not getting any size and height as well because there's no image in the specific index

Comment: I have commented out the ref to the array, I have no idea why I am still getting this error, but it doesn't fail running. I am still having a valid image that is presented in the GUI, nut I can't get the size of it for some reason

Comment: When do you try to get the size of your imageView is it in view did load because as of swift 3.0 and xcode 8 I have marked if we try to get height and width of an object from view did load it's not returning the right information I can sugest you have to look at viewWillLayoutSubviews or viewDidLayoutSubviews function and set the sizes there

Answer (score 0):

Your image view size is showing wrong because your scrollview content size is wrong. Use this method than print your image view frame. It will work

```
 override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
{
  self.scrollView1.delegate = self
  self.scrollView1.contentSize = CGSize(width:self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
}
```

Comment: Not sure how to use this in my code, and how is it related to my image size?

Comment: Use this method in your class and print your image view size